# clean url with .htaccess but with only one url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm using .htaccess to create clean urls.
here is a piece of .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^posts/page/([0-9]+)/$ posts.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^posts posts.php
```

it works fine but problem is both urls work!
is there a way to only make site.com/posts/ work and return 'not found' on site.com/posts.php(or redirect to site.com/posts/)

think i read somewhere two urls for the same page is bad for seo.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rewrite rule that returns 404 HTTP code on every ".php" URL :

```
RewriteRule .*\.php$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: now /posts/ returns 404 too. is there anyway to make only /posts.php return 404?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. Hope it will work fine for you as well.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews

#For rewriting request to posts.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/posts/?$
RewriteRule .* /posts.php [L,END]

#For returning 404 on directly accessing /posts.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/posts.php$
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect **/posts.php** to **/posts** you can use this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /posts\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /posts [NE,L,R]
#Your other rules
```

If you want to redirect the orignal request to 404 , change the RewriteRule line to this

```
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: i used it like this:RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /*\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L] and it does return 404 but it does not show my 404.php file it returns this error: Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.